# How do I connect my `bcoin` wallet to `bitcoind`?

Tags: bitcoind, wallet, regtest, spv, bcoin

I have `bitcoind` running in `regtest` mode. I want to connect my `bcoin` wallet to it and retrieve all UTXOs relevant to the sender's address.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

To run two full nodes on the same machine, they'll need to be bound to different ports. Luckily, bitcoind and bcoin run regtest on different ports already by default (`18444` and `48444` respectively). Just note this wouldn't be the case for testnet or main net.

Launch bitcoind

```
$ bitcoind -daemon -regtest
```

Launch bcoin in SPV mode

```
$ bcoin --spv --daemon --network=regtest
```

Connect bcoin to bitcoind:

```
$ bcoin-cli --network=regtest rpc addnode 127.0.0.1:18444 add
```

Get a wallet address from bcoin:

```
$ bwallet-cli --network=regtest account get default
{
  ...
  "receiveAddress": "n4C5ikvkn5HUNjqAPrPB1udnZPjm9p6xGY",
  ...
}
```

Generate a block with bitcoind, sending coinbase subsidy to the wallet address:

```
$ bitcoin-cli -regtest generatetoaddress 1 n4C5ikvkn5HUNjqAPrPB1udnZPjm9p6xGY
```

Check bcoin wallet balance:

```
$ bwallet-cli --network=regtest balance
{
  "account": -1,
  "tx": 1,
  "coin": 1,
  "unconfirmed": 5000000000,
  "confirmed": 5000000000
}
```